# How to Pool Shell Processes in Perl and/or C

Tags: python, c, perl, parallel-processing, fork

I am looking for a Perl equivalent to Python's

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
...
if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes =2)
    pool.map(Job,DATA)
```

in order to run 8 shell commands at once from a list of 28, but I don't want to use the entire machine and hurt my colleagues' jobs. I have found perl's

```
use Thread::Queue;
```

and

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
```

and

```
use Forks::Super;
```

but I am very hesitant to use external libraries/packages/modules, as I've had bad experiences with them in the past.  I'm also having a hard time getting minimal working examples from these packages to work.

Could someone please provide a standard (no external libraries/packages/modules) way of doing python's pool processing in either C or Perl without calling external libraries?

-DC

Comment: Why are you asking us to rewrite one of the perfectly good modules you listed? How is that going to provide a better experience!?

Comment: "I am very hesitant to use external libraries/packages/modules, as I've had bad experiences with them in the past" Your hesitation is understandable, but you're throwing the baby out with the bath water. Commonly-used, well-maintained modules like the ones you've listed are generally going to be much more robust than your own hand-rolled code. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: ...in general, if you're going to write a library or utility to accomplish thing-X, you want to have a deep understanding of the existing implementations **first**. If you can't get the implementations that already exist to work the way you intend, you probably don't understand the problem space well enough to build your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager).

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(8);
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
   $pm->start and next;
   exec($cmd)
      or die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super) author here:

```
use Forks::Super MAX_PROC => 8;
sub Job { ... }    # function to perform task
my @DATA = (...);  # details about 28 tasks to perform
foreach my $task (@DATA) {
    fork { cmd => 'Job', args => $task };
}
waitall;
```